# Where does IIS 7.5 log errors?

Tags: php, iis-7.5

Where does IIS 7.5 log errors?

Event Viewer?
Log File?

I get a very nonspecific internal 500 error. I would like to find out more.

I'm running PHP and I did what [this last comment](http://forums.iis.net/t/1169733.aspx) on this post said. But still it is not logging to the `C:\windows\temp` folder.

Comment: This should probably be tagged with "iis" as well. See e.g. *[Should I not use the generic tag if my solution is limited to a specific version?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265844/)*.

Comment: This may be quite different on Windows compared to Linux, but for locating the PHP error log, the canonical is *[Where does PHP store the error log? (PHP 5, Apache, FastCGI, and cPanel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/)* (despite the over-specific title). Some of the general methods described there also work on Windows.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To report errors in [Event Viewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer), go to your *php.ini* file and make sure logging is on.

```
log_errors = On
```

Then enable `error_log` to write to `syslog` (with is Event Viewer on a Windows machines)

```
error_log = syslog
```

Comment: I'm wondering why this would be useful..wouldn't it be interspersed with lots of other OS/app logs?

Comment: @SandipGangakhedkar - It's user preference. I personally like having a separate log file. But some people use network monitoring tools and they only look at Event Viewers or SysLogs.

Comment: You also need to ensure `error_reporting` and `log_errors_max_len` are properly set. E.g. `error_reporting=-1`, `log_errors_max_len=0`.

Comment: @NeerPatel, How can we set it to **server log** not `syslog` (event viewer)? By server log, I mean whatever setting IIS is currently set to.

Comment: @Pacerier - By Server Log, do you mean text file? If so, Do this : 
`error_log = C:\TEMP\PHP.LOG`

Answer (score 20):

For PHP v5.3, look here:

```
C:\Windows\Temp\PHP53_errors.log
```

Answer (score 12):

On my IIS 7.5 server I found this code in the php.ini file right down the bottom.

```
[WebPIChanges]
error_log=C:\Windows\temp\php54_errors.log
upload_tmp_dir=C:\Windows\temp
session.save_path=C:\Windows\temp
cgi.force_redirect=0
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
fastcgi.impersonate=1
fastcgi.logging=0
max_execution_time=300
date.timezone=Australia/Canberra
extension_dir="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\ext\"
```

I'm not sure if all of the above code is required because I'm not great with php.ini files but I can confirm the error log file is reachable and working.

This fix still requires the following if anyone is wondering.

```
log_errors = on
error_log = syslog
```

Answer (score 9):

I once had a problem where the error log wasn't writeable by the PHP interpreter. I added the IUSR user to the file's security permissions (right-click the file, properties, security tab) with read write and modify permissions and was then able to see PHP errors in the log file.

Comment: I tested it to work with `II_IUSRS` on windows server 2012. `IUSR` doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

There should be a "Logging" icon on the site setup in IIS.

If you haven't changed the directory for that it looks like it defaults to `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles`

Look in your settings and I'd also recommend creating a logs folder above your site files to keep your logs separated.

Comment: Those are access logs. I'm looking for error logs. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Or systemroot\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR