# PHP Error Logs on IIS 7.5/Windows Server 2008

Tags: php, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm confused about where I should be looking for a log file containing php errors on a Windows 2008 Server running IIS 7.5 (I'm more familiar with the Mac OS X setup for this).

In my php.ini file I have log_errors set to "On" but I'm not seeing any php errors in the IIS logs that appear in this folder:

C\inetpub\logs\LogFiles

Is it possible to have the php errors included in this file or do I need to specify a new file just for php errors?

(I'm trying to troubleshoot a site that is generating 500 – Internal server error for a php error. I've found this site http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/php-on-windows-server-2008-500-internal-server-error-on-iis/ that explains how I can view the error when accessing the page via an RDP session on the server, but I need to be able to log these and view the log as I won't always have RDP access).

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764230/where-does-iis-7-5-log-errors

Comment: Thanks - setting error_log = syslog and then using the Event Viewer did the trick.

Answer (score 60):

In the php.ini *(you can find this under "c:\program files (x86)\php\{PHP Version}")* change these settings:

```
log_errors = On
```

Then set *error_log* to *syslog* for the windows event log:

```
error_log = syslog
```

Or specify a location on disk such as:

```
error_log = C:\Windows\temp\php_errors.log
```

Make sure that the *error_log* or *log_error* values aren't being set elsewhere in the file.

Comment: This should be flagged as the answer.

Comment: You also need to ensure `error_reporting` and `log_errors_max_len` are properly set. E.g. `error_reporting=-1`, `log_errors_max_len=0`.

Comment: Can you report it in different file for every file? I know it is totally possible on Apache but can't find it on IIS

Answer (score -4):

If you are using xampp in windows. The error log can be find in

```
cd C:\xampp\apache\logs\
```

Use the following command to display the latest errors

```
tail -f .\error.log
```

Comment: This solution is for Apache, not for IIS as it has been asked (and as I am looking for..).