# Error in php graphic

Tags: php, graphic

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$resim  = imagecreate(250,250); 
imagejpeg($resim);
imagedestroy($resim);
```

hello ,
I wrote the above code and I got an error like in the picture.

[image]

Comment: *"I wrote the above code and I got an error like in the picture."* - ah, ok. Now, what's the question?

Comment: It's possible you haven't installed a dependency. Maybe checking your error logs will help. Read this if you need to figure out how to setup your error logging: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604695/php-error-logs-on-iis-7-5-windows-server-2008

Comment: Works fine for me! Are you sure you don't have any other code (html) in the page?

Comment: Why do I get such a result?

Comment: @CengizBulut Do you have other code (html code) in your script?

Comment: What are you expecting to see and why? Also the supplied code is not really enough to help you troubleshoot a completely empty webpage. The error could be virtually anything.

Comment: @Cengiz Bulut:  I tried your code and as Rizier123 pointed everything works fine. Check your php.ini and see the status of php_gd2.dll extension.

Comment: I want  width 250 height 250 size in a black graphic output

Comment: php_gd2.dll was enable

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the `GD Library` with your php install http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php

Comment: gd library enable but not Nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

Enable error reporting:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Enable this extension in php.ini and restart apache:

```
extension=php_gd2.dll
```