# Codeigniter returning 500 internal server error instead of error message when encountering database errors

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter, iis

Just started working with CodeIgniter this week and am encountering a weird issue that has me stumped. Whenever there are any database related errors encountered in my application I just get a 500 internal server error page. I get PHP errors for everything else, the only errors I have noticed that I get this behavior on are database related.

Two examples of this behavior:

1. I noticed this first when tried to query a database using a string for criteria to evaluate an integer field
2. Noticed this when I tried to create a database object using a reference to a database that hadn't been defined yet in `database.php`.

I have CodeIgniter running an IIS server and I am using a SQL Server for the database. I can get the application to access the database, it's just when there are errors I can't get an error message, just a 500 page.

Here are the things I've verified so far:

1. `db_debug` is set to `TRUE` in `database.php`.
2. In `index.php` the environment is set to development.
3. In `php.ini` `display_errors` is set to `On`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, not sure what else to check.

Comment: so what do your server error logs say about the internal error? that's the first thing to check. See [this](http://blog.leansentry.com/2013/07/the-server-logs-you-need-to-know-to-fix-any-iis-aspnet-error/) for details.

Comment: unfortunately, the only thing I could find in any logs was an error code of 500 0 0 in the IIS log which, from my understanding, just means that IIS doesn't know what the real problem is and would mean that the error is in PHP but I can't find any place to help me troubleshoot the error on the PHP side

Comment: ok, if there aren't any logs, have you tried enabling the [event log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764230/where-does-iis-7-5-log-errors)? that should put php errors visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up finding out that the problem was that I didn't have the appropriate user permissions assigned to the directory that Code Igniter was trying to write log files to. After fixing this, I do not seem to be having the same issue. I now just get an error message with information on the database error instead.