# session_start(); gives me 500 - Internal server error

Tags: php, mysql

i have a windows server 2012 R2 running with IIS installed on it. I have created a new website in IIS Manager and i copied my files from the 'Default' website. On the 'Default' website my PHP and all my code worked but now it gives me a 500 - Internal server error. http://85.214.59.49:90/?p=Home

I have no idea what is wrong in there but this is the code of my index.php

```
<?php
session_start();

require("system/configuration.php");

$mysql = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $mysql_database);
if(!$mysql) {
    print "ERROR: Kan niet verbinden met database";
    exit;
}
if(!$installed) {
    echo 'ERROR: Website is onder constructie';
    exit;
}
foreach(glob("system/modules/*.php") as $file) {
    require($file);
}
if(!PAGE::Exists()) {
    header("Location: ?p=Home");
}
//login the user.
if(isset($_POST['username']) AND isset($_POST['password'])) {
    user::login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
}
//logout the user.
if(isset($_POST['logout'])) {
    user::logout();
}
user::updateData();


PAGE::TOP();
PAGE::BODY();

PAGE::FOOTER();

mysql_close($mysql);
db::disconnect();
?>
```

If anyone knows whats wrong with what im doing then your help is really appreciated, also i have searched for this problem and wasn't abled to figure it out with the results i got.

Comment: You have alot of static functions there and I can't see you include any classes.

Comment: Anything in the error log?

Comment: See [Where does IIS 7.5 log errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4764230) or [Where can I find the IIS logs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6426375)

Comment: I got the log here: but there don't seem to be any errors?

http://pastebin.com/fcvzpLd1