# CKEditor large text php/IIs post to server timeouts

Tags: php, iis, ckeditor

My application has CKEditor in php application on IIS server. If post large text in editor and submit. it just spins and finally times out.  This is outside the server.Small text able to post it.

But I do same inside the sever where application deployed it works perfect. Any settings need to change for application level or CKEditor level?

Comment: Check the PHP and IIS error logs to see if it's PHP or IIS that is timing out.

Comment: where is the php logs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764230/where-does-iis-7-5-log-errors